# Kafka compare consecutive values for a key

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

We are building an application to get data from sensors. The data is streamed to Kafka from where consumers will publish it to different data stores. Each data point will have multiple attributes representing the state of the sensor.

In one of the consumers we want to publish the data to the data store only if the value has changed. for e.g. if there is temperature sensor which is polled for data every 10 secs we expect to receive data like

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Key                Value
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Sensor1            {timestamp: "10-10-2019 10:20:30", temperature: 10}
Sensor1            {timestamp: "10-10-2019 10:20:40", temperature: 10}
Sensor1            {timestamp: "10-10-2019 10:20:50", temperature: 11}
```

In the above case only the first record and the third record should be published.

For this we need some way to compare the current value for a key with the previous value with the same key. I believe this should be possible with KTable or KStream but unable to find examples.

Any help will be great!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is an example how to solve this with [`KStream#transformValues()`](https://kafka.apache.org/28/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#transformValues(org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.ValueTransformerSupplier,java.lang.String...)).

```java
StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, YourValueType>> keyValueStoreBuilder =
    Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(Stores.persistentKeyValueStore(stateStoreName),
                                Serdes.String(),
                                YourValueTypeSerde());
builder.addStateStore(keyValueStoreBuilder);
stream = builder.stream(INPUT_TOPIC, Consumed.with(Serdes.Integer(), YourValueTypeSerde()))
    .transformValues(() -> new ValueTransformerWithKey<String, YourValueType, YourValueType>() {
        private KeyValueStore<String, YourValueType> state;

        @Override
        public void init(final ProcessorContext context) {
            state = (KeyValueStore<String, YourValueType>) context.getStateStore(stateStoreName);}

        @Override
        public YourValueType transform(final String key, final YourValueType value) {
            YourValueType prevValue = state.get(key);
            if (prevValue != null) {
                if (prevValue.temperature() != value.temperature()) {
                    return prevValue;
                }
            } else {
                state.put(key, value);
            }
            return null;
       }

       @Override
       public void close() {}
    }, stateStorName))
    .to(OUTPUT_TOPIC);
```

You compare the record with the previous record stored in the state store. If temperature is different you return the record from the state store and store the current record in the state store. If the temperature is equal you discard the current record.

Comment: Would this be possible within ksqlDB? I have not found a way to use the processor API in a UDF yet, is there one?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a Kafka stream [Processor API](https://docs.confluent.io/current/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html#). You can set up a local key value store as the state context. The process function is called for each record fetched.

In the process function you can check against the last value stored and accept or reject the latest record based on business logic (in your case comparing temperature value).

In the punctuate function you can then forward the record to the consumer on a schedule. See the sample code below (without punctuate)

```java
public class SensorProcessor implements Processor<String, String> {

    private ProcessorContext context;
    private KeyValueStore<String, String> kvStore;

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
        // keep the processor context locally because we need it in punctuate() and commit()
        this.context = context;

        // retrieve the key-value store named "SensorData"
        kvStore = (KeyValueStore) context.getStateStore("SensorData");

        // schedule a punctuate() method every second based on event-time
      
    }

    @Override
    public void process(String sensorName, String sensorData) {
      
        String oldValue = this.kvStore.get(sensorName);

        if (oldValue == null) {
            this.kvStore.put(sensorName, sensorData);
        } else {
            //Put the business logic for comparison
            //compare temperatures
            //if required put the value
            this.kvStore.put(sensorName, sensorData);

            //Forward it o consumer
            context.forward(sensorName, sensorData);
        }
        context.commit();
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {
        // nothing to do
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no reason to call `context.commit()`, and you should only use it if really necessary Committing on every record has a significant overhead and can decrease the throughput.

Comment: Would this be possible within ksqlDB? I have not found a way to use the processor API in a UDF yet, is there one?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this with Kafka Streams you have to use Processor API.

You need to implement you custom `Transformer` with State store.
For each message you should search value in State store if it has changed or it is not present you should return new value, otherwise null. Apart of that you should also save that value in state store (`KeyValueStore::put(...)`)

More regarding Processor API can be found: [here](https://kafka.apache.org/23/documentation/streams/developer-guide/processor-api.html)

Comment: If you use `context.forward()` instead of just returning the value/record in the `(Value)Transformer` you lose compile-time type safety.