# Kafka stream -- Compare the previous value for a key and forward it to a target topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have two different topics as follows:

- Streams_Input_Topic
- Streams_Output_Topic

I have to create a kafka application using java to read a message from the **Streams_Input_Topic** and if the value already exists in the persistent store then I have to find the differences in the value and send the updated fields to the target topic **Streams_Output_Topic** with the same key as we received.

```
{"key":"key1", "value":{"prop1":"value1","prop2":"value2"}}
{"key":"key1", "value":{"prop1":"value1","prop2":"value4"}} ==> "prop2" is updated with new value
```

when we receive the second message with an updated value to prop2 I have to send the message to the target topic i.e. Streams_Output_Topic

```
{"key":"key1", "value":{"prop1":"value1","prop2":"value4"}}
```

I referred below link already but the whole example is not available to adopt as per my requirement.
[Kafka compare consecutive values for a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58745670/kafka-compare-consecutive-values-for-a-key)

Below is my code I am using to do the same:

```
 private void prepareStream(String topic, String appId) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Inside the prepare stream");
    String storeName = store + "-" + topic;
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, appId);
    Properties p = account.connect();
    props.putAll(p);
    props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());
    props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass());

    Path path = Paths.get("persistentKeyValueStore/kafka_streams_custom_" + topic);
    try {
        path = Files.createDirectories(path);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    LOG.info("Path : " + path.toAbsolutePath().toString());
    props.put(StreamsConfig.STATE_DIR_CONFIG, path.toAbsolutePath().toString());
    KeyValueBytesStoreSupplier stateStore = Stores.persistentKeyValueStore(storeName);
    LOG.debug("Creating Stream Object");

    StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();
    StoreBuilder<KeyValueStore<String, String>> keyValueStoreBuilder =
            Stores.keyValueStoreBuilder(Stores.persistentKeyValueStore(storeName),
                    Serdes.String(),
                    Serdes.String());
    builder.addStateStore(keyValueStoreBuilder);

    builder.stream("Streams_Input_Topic",
            Consumed.with(Serdes.String(),
            Serdes.String()))
            .transformValues(() -> new ValueTransformerWithKey<String, String, String>() {
                private KeyValueStore<String, String> state;

                @Override
                public void init(final ProcessorContext context) {
                    KafkaStreamLog.printConsole("Inside the init method of processor");
                    state = (KeyValueStore<String, String>) context.getStateStore(storeName);
                }

                @Override
                public String transform(final String key, final String value) {
                    String prevValue = state.get(key);
                    KafkaStreamLog.printConsole("Prev value : " + prevValue);
                    KafkaStreamLog.printConsole("Curr value : " + prevValue);
                    if (prevValue != null) {
                        return prevValue;
                    } else {
                        state.put(key, value);
                    }
                    return null;
                }

                @Override
                public void close() {
                }
            }, storeName).to("Streams_Output_Topic");
}
```

How do I pass the properties to the Kstream to connect to a specific broker.
If anybody can provide me with a working example that would be really helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The linked code seems to be a full example to me. What are you missing from it?

Comment: I could not find a way to pass the properties and I tried nothing is happening.

Comment: Maybe you shouldn't use `KeyValueStore<String, String>` if you want to access properties within each of the values. Use an actual POJO class and a JSON serde. Also, nothing is probably happening because you're always returning null from the transform method and have no process method to forward data to the output topic