# Suppress Duplicate Pattern

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

The pattern which we are trying to implement in java using KStream and KTable is : should be used when data that has previously been ingested is ingested again, should not be pass to the destination system.

Data is in the form of (Key, Value ) pair, where Key or Value could be combinations of multiple fields. Need reference to implement below logic :

1. If Key is different for the incoming data then it will process and send it to the destination system.
2. If Key is same then all the Values should be matched with existing values against the key in KTable, there are 2 possibilities here :
   a. All incoming values are same then it should discard it.
   b. Any value is different with previous value then should emit and send it to destination system.

In our case both source and destination systems are topics. Have referred below links but didn't get the full code. Can anyone please help here...Thanks in advance.

[Kafka stream -- Compare the previous value for a key and forward it to a target topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72982647/kafka-stream-compare-the-previous-value-for-a-key-and-forward-it-to-a-target)
[Kafka compare consecutive values for a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58745670/kafka-compare-consecutive-values-for-a-key)

Regards,
Sameer

In our case both source and destination systems are topics. Have referred below links but didn't get the full code. Can anyone please help here.

[Kafka stream -- Compare the previous value for a key and forward it to a target topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72982647/kafka-stream-compare-the-previous-value-for-a-key-and-forward-it-to-a-target)
[Kafka compare consecutive values for a key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58745670/kafka-compare-consecutive-values-for-a-key)